# C# Value from another List linked to value

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the productname from the List where it matches the Productid from the List using LINQ but I have no luck.

The ProductID is in both lists and It should be linked somehow.

I tried:

```
Product product = products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductName == orderDetail.ProductID);


        List<orderDetail> orderDetails = Database.getOrderDetails();
        List<Product> products = Database.getProducts();

        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(orderDetail.OrderID);
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Productname);
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(orderDetail.UnitPrice);
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(orderDetail.Quantity);
        textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(orderDetail.Discount);
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Can you rephrase/elaborate?

Comment: What is `OrderID` in the lamba expression in your 4th statement?

Comment: What is `Productname` a property of in this line: `Convert.ToString(Productname);`. Is it a property of `product`, such that `product.Productname` would do what you want? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Does that even compile? Where is `Productname` declared? Shouldn't the code be `textBox2.Text = orderDetail.ProductName;`?

Comment: @Jakotheshadows the orderDetail List doesn't contain the Productname, the list Product does. But those two are linked by a common ProductID.

Comment: @JamesFaix it is something to be ignored, I added it by accident.

Comment: Is this correct: You have two lists that you want to match by ProductID.  One is a master product list, and one is the list of products in an order, these must be matched by productID. You want to get the name of some product in your order from the master product list?

Comment: @JamesFaix that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this, but it's not very clear how your Product and Order objects are structured.  (You'll also probably want some null checks.)

```
OrderDetails orderDetails = Database.GetOrderDetails().First();
List<Product> products = Database.GetProducts();

var name = products.First(p => p.ProductID == orderDetails.ProductID).ProductName;
```

Comment: It gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: Sorry, I used `=` in the lambda where I meant `==`.  Try with that switched

Comment: This works like a charm, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why matching `x.ProductName` with `orderDetail.ProductID` here: `Product product = products.FirstOrDefault(x =>  == orderDetail.ProductID);`? 
If you're trying to get the product of the list with products, that matches the `ProductID` of your orderDetail, you'll just have to do it like that:

```
Product product = products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == orderDetail.ProductID);
```

If, of course, both `Product` and the class of your `orderDetail` object have the same `.ProductID` property. 
Or I've missunderstood something?

Answer (score -2):

Modify the earlier query, I quess you need the results as follows.
         This query would return all the product names whose productid exists in both the list.
         There are two ways we can achieve this results set.

```
List<orderDetail> orderDetails = Database.getOrderDetails();
List<Product> products = Database.getProducts();

// This is a SQL like query 
var productNames =  from ord in orderDetails 
join pr in products 
on ord.ProductID equals pr.ProductID 
select pr.ProductName;

Alternativey, You can also use `Join()`

//This is extention method query
var productNames = orderDetails.Join(products, 
ord => ord.ProductID,
                       pr => pr.ProductID, 
(orderdetail, productdetail) =>  productdetail.ProductName);
```

Comment: Modify the query as you need the results set